# Run Junit test in several threads. Can Gatling execute JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I need to run existing functional autotests in several threads same time (number of threads will be set in param ) with the aim of load testing.
Functional autotest is written in Java with JUnit and is launching from Jenkins.
Is there any way to implement this task without recording the scenario in the Jmeter?
I heard about the possibility of running tests written in Java in the Gatling framework.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unit tests are not intended for load testing, so it's not that it can't be done - usually it shouldn't be done. There should be separate script that is built to test your app under load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using library https://github.com/encircled/jPut. This is exactly what you are describing: using unit tests for perf/load/stress testing with easy integration with CI pipelines thanks to JUnit. Tests itself can be written in any JVM language.